# How to create a perfect sequence between two numbers in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In google sheets I'm needing to fill in values between a range of two numbers which go from negative to positive. And I need to fill in this range evenly. It looks as follows.

```
Rows
1  | -0.020
2  | ---
3  | ---
4  | ---
5  | ---
6  | ---
7  | 0.040
```

-0.020 being (min) and 0.040 (max). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put in in `A2`:

```
=ArrayFormula(SEQUENCE(ROW(A7)-ROW(A1)-1)*(A7-A1)/(ROW(A7)-ROW(A1))+A1)
```